# JavaScript Readonly attribute

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem with a JavaScript readonly field. I have a textboxes which I am making readonly.

```
 if(val == true)
{    
    ddlCnt.value=objRec.iCntId;
    tAdd1.value=objRec.sAddress1;        
    tAdd2.value=objRec.sAddress2;        
    tCity.value=objRec.sCity;
    tState.value=objRec.sState;
    tZip.value=objRec.sZip;

    //tAdd1.disabled = tAdd2.disabled = tCity.disabled = tState.disabled = tZip.disabled = ddlCnt.disabled = true;
    //tAdd1.disabled = tAdd2.disabled = tCity.disabled = tState.disabled = tZip.disabled = ddlCnt.disabled = true;
    tAdd1.setAttribute("readonly", true);
    tAdd2.setAttribute("readonly", true);
    tCity.setAttribute("readonly", true);
    tState.setAttribute("readonly", true);
    tZip.setAttribute("readonly", true);
}
```

It is working fine.
Now to deactivate this readonly property I used

```
else
{    
    tAdd1.value = tAdd2.value = tCity.value = tState.value = tZip.value = "";        
    //tAdd1.disabled = tAdd2.disabled = tCity.disabled = tState.disabled = tZip.disabled = ddlCnt.disabled = false;
    ddlCnt.value="-1";
    vsRec.innerHTML='';     
    tAdd1.setAttribute("readonly", false);
    tAdd2.setAttribute("readonly", false);
    tCity.setAttribute("readonly", false);
    tState.setAttribute("readonly", false);
    tZip.setAttribute("readonly", false);

    //vsRec.style.visibility='hidden';             
}
```

But it is not working at all. Can any one please help me out of this problem or any suggestion or tips that can help me a lot regarding this (and why this is not working?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the attribute with [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute).

```
tAdd1.removeAttribute("readonly");
tAdd2.removeAttribute("readonly");
tCity.removeAttribute("readonly");
tState.removeAttribute("readonly");
tZip.removeAttribute("readonly");
```

Comment: I will must accept your answer. It is not giving the permission to accept your answer before 3 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the readonly attribute, e.g.:

```
tAdd1.removeAttribute("readonly");
```

Answer (score 3):

`readonly` is not a true/false attribute, it's a present/not-present attribute.  You need to remove the attribute, not set it to false.

Answer (score 3):

The presence of the readonly attribute causes the input box to become read-only, not setting it to true or false. Remove the attributes.